# error: no matching function for call

Tags: c++

Can any body please help me solve this problem. I have a class `Comm` that stores elements of another class `Info` in its map container:

```
    #include<map>
using namespace std;
class En
{

};

class Info
{
public:
    const En * en;
    bool read;
    bool write;
    bool done;
    Info(
            En * en_,
            bool read_,
            bool write_,
            bool done_
            )
    :
        en(en_),
        read(read_),
        write(write_),
        done(done_)
    {}

    Info(const Info& info_)
    :
        en(info_.en),
        read(info_.read),
        write(info_.write),
        done(info_.done)
    {}


};

class Comm
{
    std::map<const En*,Info> subscriptionList;
public:
void  subscribeEn(Info value)
{
    //none of the below works
//  subscriptionList[value.en] = Info(value);
    subscriptionList[value.en] = value;
}
};


int main()
{

//  En * en;
//  bool read;
//  bool write;
//  bool Done;
//  Comm comm;
//  Info Info_(en,read,write,Done);
//  comm.subscribeEn(Info_);
//  return 1;

}
```

but I get the following error in compilation:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/map:61:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h: In instantiation of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = const En*; _Tp = Info; _Compare = std::less<const En*>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const En* const, Info> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Info; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = const En*]’:
test.cpp:47:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:458:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Info::Info()’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_map.h:458:11: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:28:2: note: Info::Info(const Info&)
test.cpp:28:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:15:2: note: Info::Info(En*, bool, bool, bool)
test.cpp:15:2: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
```

I appreciate if you let me know why I get this and how to solve it.
thank you

Comment: `map::operator[]` needs to create an object (if it isn't already) before it can be assigned to. How will it create that object other than with a default constructor?

Comment: I provided a couple of constructors for Info class but couldn't fix it. can you please help me witht hat? thanks

Comment: If you're totally against having a default constructor, you'll have to use `insert` (or similar) and `at`. Subscripting it creates defaulted values in the map.

Comment: Wow, nice. I make sure to use that. But answer to your basic question is no! I am not against default or copy constructor. I just don't know how to make use of them correctly. I am curious to c why the code isn't working and how to fix it (without using insert or at in the first place). I added copy constructor too Now. Any Idea?

Comment: Just add a constructor with no (or defaulted) parameters and initialize the object the way you want in it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to initialize my object in the constructor without a supporting parameter. Maybe it is not possible at all!?? maybe I should just use insert instead of map::operator[] ?? if it is so, please make your comment as an answer. I will mark it as true.thanks

Comment: You'd do it the same way you have now, but with default values. If it doesn't make sense for that class, don't force one in there, and use `insert` and `at` instead.

Comment: @rahman Here's one way that you would implement a default constructor: `Info() : en(nullptr), read(false), write(false), done(false) {}`. Of course, since I don't know what this class is, the "default" values here might not make sense. Specially since your pointer is declared as `const`, which means you can't change it after (or even inside) the constructor. Anyhow, just follow the other advice and use `insert` with maps of this specific class.

Comment: I just did that. thanks. is anybody going to turn his comment to an answer? I am eager to mark it as true :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, that problem is here:

```
class Comm
{
    std::map<const En*,Info> subscriptionList;
public:
    void  subscribeEn(Info value)
    {
        //none of the below works
        //  subscriptionList[value.en] = Info(value);
        subscriptionList[value.en] = value;
    }
};
```

I guess, that `std::map` first instantiates a pair with `const En*` and `Info` and then makes an assignment to fields of this pair. You haven't provided a parameterless constructor for `Info` and that's why compiler complains.

You can solve this by adding the following to your Info class:

```
// Default, parameterless constructor
Info()
{
    // Some default values
    en = NULL; // or nullptr in C++11
    read = false;
    write = false;
    done = false;
}
```

Another solution is to change definition of std::map, such that it contains a pointer to Info rather than its instance:

```
std::map<const En *,Info *> subscriptionList;
```

Comment: This is the right answer, although what you say about the definition of the class isn't correct, since there are no `const` data members (rather, a pointer to const).

Comment: Aww crap. You're right, I confused `const En *` with `En * const` :)

Comment: That's an easy mistake to make! BTW it seems that all OP needs now is someone to give them an example on how to write the default constructor.

Comment: @Spook just a question. Suppose I added the Default, parameterless constructor as you advised. what will be assigned to the map when I execute "subscriptionList[value.en] = value;" ? default values? or real values stored in "value" parameter?

Comment: Real values. If the entry already exists, it will call `operator =` on the existing Info entry. Otherwise, it will create a new std::pair with provided key and empty instance of Info and immediately after will call `operator =` on that instance, so you'll end up with properly initialized entry.

Comment: TL;DR yes, it will have real values :)

Comment: I got the same error in a different situation, despite having defined a default constructor for the container element class: By applying an algorithm with a custom `Compare` the compiler complained about
   `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), MyCompare())`
in case I defined the struct `MyCompare` locally in the method where `sort()` was called.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect capitalization of `done`:

```
bool Done;
Info Info_(en,read,write,done);
```

Typically  lowercase or camelCase are used for variable names.

Comment: yes I will edit that. But that is not the source of the problem

Comment: dude, a typo wasn't the topic of this question

Comment: It certainly *was* the topic, especially considering it was one of the errors listed in your build output. Now that you've edited the question it's irrelevant. That's your fault, not mine.